# c pointer deferencing and arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers, ubuntu, gdb

```
int main(void)
{
    int *x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    x = &y
    *x = 1

    *(x+1) = 10
    return 0;
}
```

When I perform `*(x+1) = 10` and try to print out the address of x, it points to `0x7fff0000000a` and get this when I try to print out the value of x `Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff0000000a`

Before `*(x+1) = 10`, the address of x comes out to `(int *) 0x7fffffffe4d4` and the value of x comes out to `1`

The question I have is, what exactly is  `*(x+1) = 10` doing? The address of x and y are 4 bytes apart. Since x points to y, and x was added 1, it should point back to x itself

Address of x:
`(int **) 0x7fffffffe4d8`
Address of y:
`(int *) 0x7fffffffe4d4`

Comment: Do you expect the address of `y` and `x + 1` to be the same?  It's unsafe to make this assumption.

Comment: What? Anyway, you haven't allocated space past x, so I don't see why your trying to use ptr arithmetic on it. Research before you post!

Comment: Also, what does gdb or ubantu have to do with this? Here's the tag wiki definition: `Ubuntu is a free desktop and server operating system based on Debian GNU/Linux. Note that this is for programming questions specific to Ubuntu and http://askubuntu.com is dedicated to answering general Ubuntu questions.` With emphasis on **specific to Ubantu**. This is a generic problem.

Comment: this line: '*(x+1) = 10' corrupted the stack resulting in undefined behaviour which can/will lead to a seg fault event

Comment: pointer arithmetic has the feature that adding '1' results in the initial pointer value being incremented by the sizeof the underlying pointer type.  Since an int is 4 bytes long and this is a pointer to int,  adding 1 results in 4 being added to the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what exactly is  `*(x+1) = 10` doing?

It re-interprets `x` as a pointer to the initial element of an array, and tries to access that "array"'s second member (i.e. an item at index `1`). Since `x` is neither an array nor a pointer into an array, the assignment is undefined behavior.

> The address of `x` and `y` are `4` bytes apart.

This happens to be the case with your compiler. It may be different on other systems, depending on many factors, such as the compiler, the optimization flags, the size of a pointer, the size of an `int`, and so on. The important thing is that no matter where `x+1` points, it is illegal to dereference it, because `x` points to a scalar local variable.

Comment: Why has the original address of x changed after the assignment? Does `(x+1)` change the address of x?

Comment: @Aaron Its undefined behavior which means the compiler can __do anything__.

Comment: @Aaron `x+1` is an expression. It adds `sizeof(*x)` bytes to the raw value of `x`. This is convenient for accessing arrays through pointers. When `x` points to an initial element of an array (i.e. the element at index `0`), `x+1` points to element at index `1`, `x+2` points to element at index `2`, and so on. The size of an array element is factored into the calculations automatically.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm asking what `*(x+1) = 10` does, not `(x+1)`

Comment: It raises a segmentation fault for illegal access of an array index beyond allocated memory. Its undefined meaning **anything goes** including but not limited to: corruption of data, sudden crashes, overwriting system data, and more.

Comment: @Aaron I was answering your "Does `(x+1)` change the address of `x`?" comment. As far as `*(x+1) = 10` assignment is concerned, it looks like the particular kind of undefined behavior on your system happens to change the content of `x`, i.e. the address stored in it. The address of `x` itself (i.e. `&x`) stays the same; it cannot be changed.